# How to remove blank pages when extract PDF from RDLC

Tags: model-view-controller, rdlc

I have (paper size:legal,landscape)  rdlc report When I tried to extract pdf from RDLC report.I'm getting each even page as blank page. I don't know how to resolve this issue. I tried  **Set ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace = True** But its not working. If you ther any page setting then tell me the exact height & width for Legal size. Please give the exact solution.

Im Using
Rdlc report v15
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Make the report Width Perfect and Height 
remove extra blank space from bottom of the report where no data available